# SQL Query for displaying balance using MS Access 2010 Database - There is form within a form

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

The below query i wrote works fine and shows me Sum of amount paid from the BUDGET amount. But it isn't showing remaining balance. I would appreciate your help in identifying the logic/query to display balance amount.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW tblInvoices.FY, tblInvoices.ContractNumber, 
       Sum(tblInvoices.AmountPaid) AS [Sum Of AmountPaid]
FROM tblInvoices
GROUP BY tblInvoices.FY, tblInvoices.ContractNumber
HAVING (((tblInvoices.FY)=[which FY]));
```

Please find the attached screenshots for the reference. There is a form within a form. When i click button (YTD Spent), the form appears and displays information about (Sum of Amount), (Budget) but not the (Balance = Budget - Sum of Amount) in Balance text box. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1PpE.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZY6L.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXSWy.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the work around @Daniel,based on that i studied and wrote the below query which works perfectly fine.                                           SELECT DISTINCTROW tblInvoices.FY, tblInvoices.ContractNumber, Sum(tblInvoices.AmountPaid)

AS [Sum Of AmountPaid],tblBudget.Budget, tblBudget.Budget-Sum(tblInvoices.AmountPaid) AS [Balance#]

FROM tblInvoices, tblBudget

where  tblInvoices.FY=tblBudget.FiscalYear and tblInvoices.ContractNumber=tblBudget.ContractNumber

GROUP BY tblInvoices.FY, tblInvoices.ContractNumber,tblBudget.Budget

HAVING (((tblInvoices.FY)=[which FY]));

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess here cause have no idea what the DB table structure is

```
select b.*, a.budget-b.[Sum Of AmountPaid] from (SELECT DISTINCTROW tblInvoices.FY, tblInvoices.ContractNumber, 
       Sum(tblInvoices.AmountPaid) AS [Sum Of AmountPaid]
FROM tblbudget
GROUP BY tblInvoices.FY, tblInvoices.ContractNumber
HAVING (((tblInvoices.FY)=[which FY])))a join
(
SELECT DISTINCTROW tblInvoices.FY, tblInvoices.ContractNumber, 
       Sum(tblInvoices.AmountPaid) AS [Sum Of AmountPaid]
FROM tblInvoices
GROUP BY tblInvoices.FY, tblInvoices.ContractNumber
HAVING (((tblInvoices.FY)=[which FY])))b
on a.fy=b.fy and a.contractnumber=b.contractnumber
```

Comment: Thank you for the work around @Daniel,based on that i studied and wrote the above query which works perfectly fine.